# Open chrome with content of clipboard

Tags: google-chrome, clipboard, xclip

Lets say I have a URL in my clipboard, if I run on the terminal:

```
xclip -o
```

It will echo the domain, I would like to use this content as a variable to put on the command:

```
google-chrome --enable-plugins -incognito "www.clipboard_content_here.com"
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
google-chrome --enable-plugins -incognito "www.$(xclip -o).com"
```